# Error: EntityTooLarge Status 400 AmazonAWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, file-upload, filesize

I'm trying to upload a video from a Cordova app to an Amazon AWS S3 bucket from an Android/iPhone. But it's failing sometimes, giving sporadic reports of this error from AWS bucket:

```
http_status:400,
<Code>EntityTooLarge</Code>
```

Some of the files are tiny, some around 300mb or so.

What can I do to resolve this at the AWS end?

Comment: whats the size of the video and how you are uploading it to S3.

Comment: Edited question descripiton.

Answer (score 1):

The `400 Bad Request` error is sometimes used by S3 to indicate conditions that make the request in some sense invalid -- not just syntactically invalid, which is the traditional sense of 400 errors.

> `EntityTooLarge`
>
> Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed object size.
>
> `400 Bad Request`
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

Note the word "proposed."  This appears to be a reaction to the `Content-Length` request header you are sending.  You may want to examine that.  Perhaps the header is inconsistent with the actual size of the file, or the file is being detected as larger than it actually is.

Note that while the maximum *object* size in S3 is 5 TiB, the maximum *upload* size is 5 GiB.  (Objects larger than 5 GiB have to be uploaded in multiple parts.)

Answer (score 0):

413 errors occur when the request body is larger than the server is configured to allow. I believe its not the error which AWS S3 is throwing because they support 5 TB size of object.

If you are first accepting this video in your app and from there you are making request to amazon S3, then your server is not configure to accept the large entities in request.

Refer -[set-entity-size for different servers](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file%20set-entity-size%20for%20different%20servers). if your server is not listed here, then you need to figure out how to increase entity size for your server.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Thing is, it's a 400, not 413 error.  Don't know if that's significant.  Also, the files are a few hundred mb, maybe a multipart data issue?

Comment: @Dave it depends on the implementation anyway 4XX are client error.